# Methods that local values are created in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, optimization

I have been wondering how local values are creating and destroyed in JavaScript for example

`function multiple(value){return value*2;}`

when I called this function will a local variable be created `value` and then would it be destroyed?
Or would it affect garbage collection and become something to be removed?
And would that also apply to Java?

Please don't say premature optimization is the root of all evil, I know that already.
if this is a bad question please dont -rep me, just say so and I'll delete it

Comment: Not a stupid question.. but google would have served you better than S.O. http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass

Comment: Thanks but I couldn't figure out what it would be called or what keywords would be used to describe it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript, `value` is an argument to the function and it will be created at the time the function is called.  Another variable is then created as the result of the `value*2` expression and that result is then returned from the function.

There are no `local variables` in the normal sense of that word since none are declared in that function.  Arguments to the function work kind of like local variables (same scope, same default lifetime), but people don't normally call them local variables.

If the return value from that function is assigned to something as in:

```
var result = multiple(3);
```

Then, the return value will live on in the `result` variable.  If the return value is not assigned and not used (which would be odd in this case), then it will have no references to it and will be freed by the the garbage collector.

Comment: But would it add onto the heap become something that will be removed by garbage collector?(am making a game and i really need to get all the juice out of the code to make it faster since its for android and I plan to add a lot of math)

Comment: @androidmaster - would what add onto the heap?

Comment: sorry I used the wrong word, I mean garbage collection (I was thinking about java for a moment)

Comment: @androidmaster - I don't know what item you're asking about.  Which item?  As I say in my answer, the returned value from the function is an allocated variable.  It will be garbage collected if not assign by the caller.

Comment: Thanks, i was talking about the allocated variable oops, sorry I was trying to answer some other question